# Streaming does not work in Flask + paramiko

Tags: python, flask, paramiko

I have a remote host on which I run a turbostat through a paramiko (a turbostat displays temperature, power, and load CPU in a cycle). Stdout paramiko receives from the remote host a data-string from turbostat in cycle. 
I want to send this output stream to Flask to see the stream on the web, but now my code receive on web only one string

````
    app = Flask(__name__)
    apply_config(app, config)

  app.add_url_rule('/api/host/<comp>/turbostat', 'turbostat', turbostat)

    return app



def turbostat(comp):
    def inner():
        ip_addr = get_eine_ip_addr(comp)
        print(ip_addr)
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(hostname=ip_addr, username='root', password='1', port=22, timeout=20)
        sin, sout, serr = ssh.exec_command(""" turbostat -S | awk '{print "%Busy:"$2, "Bzy_MHz:"$3, "CoreTmp:"$10, "PkgWatt:"$16}' """)
        for line in line_buffered(sout):
            print(line)
            return line

    return flask.Response(inner(), mimetype='text/html')

def line_buffered(f):
    while not f.channel.exit_status_ready():
        yield str(f.readline())```
````

Comment: what if you remove `while not f.channel.exit_status_ready():` or replace it with if statement, will it work ? what about replacing `print(line)` with `yield str(sout.readline())` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found right way:

```
def turbostat(comp):
    ip_addr = get_eine_ip_addr(comp)
    print(ip_addr)
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(hostname=ip_addr, username='root', password='1', port=22, timeout=20)
    sin, sout, serr = ssh.exec_command(""" turbostat -S | awk '{print "%Busy:"$2, "Bzy_MHz:"$3, "CoreTmp:"$10, "PkgWatt:"$16}' """)
    def line_buffered(f):
        while not f.channel.exit_status_ready():
            yield str(f.readline())

    return flask.Response(line_buffered(sout), mimetype='text/plain')
```

Answer (score 0):

You break your loop on the first line:

```
for line in line_buffered(sout):
    print(line)
    return line
```

Not sure what you want the `turbostat` to do. But if you want to print a complete output, just do:

```
print(sout.read())
```

(and you do not even need the `line_buffered`).